# Couchbase Client (Java) IlegalStateException - Check object validity

Tags: java, scalability, couchbase

I'm using Apache Commons Pool for storing a set of Couchbase Clients. When doing load tests (but still with a small load), after a couple thousand operations (using a 100 connections pool) some Couchbase Client Objects start throwing IlegalStateException and then they shutdown.

I would like to know if there is a way to check if a CouchbaseClient object is still valid for being used. The Exception is generated when a "set" operation is called from the object, so checking if the client is valid would be an acceptable solution.

I'm still not sure what is the origin of the Exception. However, when I do a  sort of validation of the client before returning to the pool, the problem stops happening. The issue is that this validation (calling a set operation to test if the client is working) is too brute force and impacts performance. I would like to find a smoother way of checking this.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of `IllegalStateException` is that is wasn't possible to add an operation to the input queue. See the [Bullet-Proof Futures and Listeners](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-java-1.4/#bullet-proof-futures-and-listeners) section in the Couchbase Java Developer Guide on how to handle it.

Note however that 100 `CouchbaseClient` objects is **a lot**! You generally don't need more than one or two `CouchbaseClient` object per application - the recommended use-case is asynchronous and there is an internal thread pool for handling the actual low-level operations.

I'd recommend looking at the [Couchbase Java Developer Guide](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-java-1.4), specifically the section on [Understanding and Using Asynchronous Operations](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-java-1.4/#understanding-and-using-asynchronous-operations).